# US agencies forms data set

Tags: government, uses-of-open-data

Is there an API or a dataset of all US administrative forms?
I tried many searches without great success

Comment: You mean all the 'paperwork' everywhere across the US???

Answer (score 1):

Without looking into this at all, I'm going to say that no, there is no comprehensive dataset/API of all US administrative forms.
That said, you may find help/references/resources by contacting these groups: [Center for Civic Design](https://civicdesign.org/), [Civic by Design](http://www.civicbydesign.com/), the people behind [Civic Design Camp](http://civicdesigncamp.org/), and [the Lab @ DC](http://thelab.dc.gov/), which very recently held "Form-a-palooza", an event for designing gov forms.

Again, this answer may very well be wrong; if so, I'm more than happy to delete it.

Also, if I am right and this dataset does not exist, perhaps you could start it? Creating a repository on GitHub and adding the forms/documenting their origins is where I would start.